# Leaflet EasyButton

Tags: leaflet

I am using EasyButton plugin and more specifically its toggle option. In this option, two different functions can be assigned to a single button. The button is working very smooth with simple functions, but whenever I write an if statement it stops working. I am trying to find out if I make a mistake in the statement.

danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples

Below is my code:

```
 var toggle = L.easyButton ('<span>legend OFF</span>',{
 states: [{
     stateName: 'add-markers',
icon: '<span>voir la légende</span>',
title: 'add random markers',
onClick: function(control) {
    map.removeControl(legend0);
    map.removeControl(legend1);
    map.removeControl(legend2);
    map.removeControl(legend3);
          control.state('remove-markers');
}}, {
    icon:'<span>masquer la légende</span>',
    stateName: 'remove-markers',
  title: 'remove markers' ,
  onClick: function(control) {
  map.addControl(btn2);
  control.state('add-markers');
},
    }]
    });
     toggle.addTo(map);


   var btn2= L.easyButton( '<span>legend ON</span>', function showlegend() {

   if(map.getZoom()<12){  
        map.addControl(legend12);                   
        map.removeControl(legend0);}    


       if(map.getZoom()==12){

        map.removeControl(legend12);                    
        map.addControl(legend0);}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Also, what exactly is the issue that you are trying to overcome?

Comment: I am using EasyButton plugin and more specifically its toggle option. In this option, two different functions can be assigned to a single button. http://danielmontague.com/projects/easyButton.js/v1/examples/       The button is working very smooth with simple functions, but whenever I write an if statement it stops working. I am trying to find out if I make a mistake in the statement. @Barbarossa

Comment: I found out, it is a mistake in my code. @Barbarossa